# How to autogenerate python data parser for C++ structs?

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ based application logging data to files and I want to load that data in Python so I can explore it.  The data files are flat files with a known number of records per file. The data records are represented as a struct (nested structs) in my C++ application. This struct (subtructs) change regularly during my development process, so I also have to make associated changes to my Python code that loads the data. This is obviously tedious and doesn't scale well. What I am interested in is a way to automate the process of updating the Python code (or some other way to handle this problem altogether). I am exploring some libraries that convert my C++ structs to other formats such as JSON, but I have yet to find a solid solution.  Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

- Consider using data serialization system / format that has C++ and Python bindings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats
  (e.g. protobuf or even json or csv)
- Alternatively consider writing a library in C that reads the data end exposes them as structures. Then use: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html to call this C library and retrieve records

Of course if semantics of the data changes (e.g. new important field needs to by analyzed) you will have to handle that new stuff in the python code. No free lunch.

Comment: I have tried JSON, but it is not performant enough.  My data is entirely numeric and there is lots of it (it is a scientific instrument).  My current idea is to generate a JSON file of the struct that represents each record (dtype like format), but I am falling short.